# correcting Henry's Law coefficient for higher pressure

Tags: thermodynamics

I have a bottle at room temperature that contains water, nitrogen, and a trace amount of vinyl chloride (VC). I'm trying to determine how much the Henry's law coefficient for VC (at 25 C and 1 bar, with units of pressure/concentration) should be corrected if the bottle is pressurized to 2 bar.

A thermodynamics textbook I've borrowed [states](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Engineering_and_Chemical_Thermodynamics/wqdsDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=engineering%20and%20chemical%20thermodynamics&pg=PA422&printsec=frontcover) that the Henry's law coefficient $H_2$ at pressure $P_2$ can be calculated with $H_1$ at $P_1$ as follows:

$$
H_2 = H_1 \exp \left [ \int\limits_{P_1}^{P_2} \frac{\bar{V}^\infty}{RT}dP \right ]
$$

where $\bar{V}^\infty$ is the partial molar volume at infinite dilution, $R$ is the gas constant, and $T$ is temperature. The textbook says that $\bar{V}^\infty$ can be approximated with the pure species molar volume $V^m$, [which for VC](https://polymerdatabase.com/polymers/polyvinylchloride.html) is 45.2 mL/mol.

After making that substitution and simplifying I am left with the following approximation:

$$
H_2 \approx H_1 \exp \left [ \frac{V^m(P_2 - P_1)}{RT} \right ]
$$

which for my scenario works out to a negligible adjustment of $H_2\approx1.0018H_1$. Have I interpreted this material correctly?